# Grab return value from python with Shell Script

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, shell

I am aware that a similar kind of question has already been asked and answered.
However, my question deals with a slightly different type of problem and implementation:

The situation is: 
I need to build a shell script which will capture the return value of a python (2.7) script, which will then be used in a jenkins job. 
In the python script, I have to read an SVN checkout text file and return the value of the file, update the value of the file, and commit it.

I have implemented the following code:

```
swdl_number_receiver.py

import posixpath
import os
import sys
import subprocess

SVN_VERSION_DIR_PATH = 'data'
SWDL_FILE_NAME = "swdl_number.txt"

# Exit codes
class ExitCode:
   """ Exit code Enumeration """
    SUCCESS = 0
    FAILURE = 1

# get SWDL number from the file
def getSWDLNumber():
work_dir = posixpath.join(os.getcwd(),SVN_VERSION_DIR_PATH)
version_number = None
new_version_number = None

# Read the File
os.chdir(work_dir)
with open(SWDL_FILE_NAME, "r") as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        version_number = str.strip(line)
        if version_number is None:
            print "---- SWDL NUmber is empty existing the code ....... "
            sys.exit(ExitCode.FAILURE)
        else:
            print "++++ The found SWDL number is : " + version_number
            new_version_number = int(version_number) + 1
            print "++++ The New SWDL Number is  : " + str(new_version_number)

print "++++ Writing the new SWDL Number from " + str(version_number) + " to " + str(new_version_number)
#replace the file with new content
os.remove(SWDL_FILE_NAME)
with open(SWDL_FILE_NAME, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(str(new_version_number).rstrip('\n'))

checkin_message = '"Updated SWDL Number to : ' + str(new_version_number) + '"'
try:
    subprocess.call(['svn', 'commit', '-m ' + checkin_message, SWDL_FILE_NAME, '--non-interactive'])
except:
    sys.exit(ExitCode.FAILURE)

return new_version_number


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print getSWDLNumber()
```

In my shell script I am doing:

```
outputString=$(python swdl_number_receiver.py)
echo $outputString
```

The swdl_number.txt contains only one line with 5 digits.

**My problem:**
When I comment out all the "print" lines and the try and catch for the SVN commit, I get only new_version_number as the return value. 
In other words, If I uncomment all the lines with print statements and the try and catch block for SVN commit, then on the shell script as $output_string I get every print statements and the commit message as well as the "new_version_number". And If I comment out all the print statement and try and catch block then I am getting the desired "new_version_number".

How should my code be modified in order to get the only required "new_version_number" return, and display all print lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
outputString=$(python swdl_number_receiver.py)
```

construction captures text sent to `stdout`. If you want your script to print information to the terminal then you can send it to `stderr`. Here's a simple demo.

**qtest.py**

```
import sys

print >>sys.stderr, "this is sent to stderr"
print "this is sent to stdout"
```

In Bash:

```bash
$ outputString=$(python qtest.py);echo "ok";echo "$outputString"
```

**output**

```
this is sent to stderr
ok
this is sent to stdout
```

---

Here's a version of **qtest.py** that works on Python 2 and Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

print("this is sent to stderr", file=sys.stderr)
print("this is sent to stdout")
```

---

If you also want to capture the output sent to `stderr` in a variable, one way to do that, without changing "qtest.py", is to redirect `stderr` in Bash to a file:

```bash
$ outputString=$(python qtest.py 2>qtemp);echo "ok";stderrString=$(<qtemp);echo "STDOUT: $outputString";echo "STDERR: $stderrString"
ok
STDOUT: this is sent to stdout
STDERR: this is sent to stderr
```

A better way is to write directly to the file in Python:

**qtest.py**

```python
from __future__ import print_function

with open("qtemp", "w") as f:
    print("this is sent to qtemp", file=f)
    print("this is sent to stdout")
```

**bash**

```bash
$ outputString=$(python qtest.py);echo "ok";qtempString=$(<qtemp);echo "STDOUT: $outputString";echo "qtemp: $qtempString"
ok
STDOUT: this is sent to stdout
qtemp: this is sent to qtemp
```

Comment: Yes your implementation is what I was looking for , however How can I capture this `sys.stderr` in a variable . Because I need to sore this in a variable so that I can use the value later.

Comment: @Nepal12 I've added some more info to my answer, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can share your `version file` between python and bash. Depending on exit code of your python script you can decide whether you got valid new version.

**Shell script:**

```
# Version file name
SWDL_FILE_NAME="x.txt"
export SWDL_FILE_NAME
python swdl_number_receiver.py
# Exit code of python script
EXIT_CODE=$?

if [ $EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ] ; then
        # If scripts exits successfully get version
        NEW_VERSION=$(cat $SWDL_FILE_NAME)
        echo "New version is $NEW_VERSION"
        exit 0
else
        # No new version
        echo "Failed to get new version"
        exit 1
fi
```

**Minimal Python File:**

```
import sys
import os
SWDL_FILE_NAME=os.environ['SWDL_FILE_NAME']
with open(SWDL_FILE_NAME, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("111")
sys.exit(0)
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./myscript.sh 
New version is 111
```